# How to execute a function only once in voice draw(); but still have it displayed for the whole animation

Tags: processing

I'm struggling with something here.

Basically I made an animation with several functions. I want the functions to be animated, except for one that I want to be still.

If I specify `noLoop`, then nothing gets animated, if I tell the function to run a set number of times, then after that number it stops being displayed. What I want is to have it run once but then be still displayed.

Do you guys have any idea of how I could do that ?

Here is the code :

```java
int r1,r2,r3 = 0;
int i1, i2,i3;

void setup(){
    size(800,800);
    background(255,0);
    //noLoop();
}

void draw(){
    background(255,0);
    rosace();

    croix();
    sillon1();
    sillon2();
}

void rosace(){
    for (i1 = 0;i1<230; i1++){

        rectMode(CENTER);

        noFill();
        stroke(20);
        strokeWeight(1);


        pushMatrix();
        translate(width/2,height/2);
        translate(400,400);
        rotate(radians(r1));
        rect(0,0,400,400);
        r1 +=1;
        //println(r);

        popMatrix();
        println("rosace ex");
    }
}

void croix(){

    pushMatrix();
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(0);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    rotate(radians(45));
    line(-10,0,10,0);
    line(0,-10,0,10);
    popMatrix();
}

void sillon1(){
    for (i2 =0; i2<360; i2++){
        pushMatrix();

        translate(width/2,height/2);
        strokeWeight(int(random(0,7)));

        rotate(radians(r2));

        point(-330,0);

        popMatrix();
        r2 +=1;
    }
}

void sillon2(){
    for (i2 =0; i2<2000; i2++){
        pushMatrix();

        translate(width/2,height/2);
        strokeWeight(int(random(1,3)));

        rotate(radians(r2));

        point(-360,0+(random(-2,2)));

        popMatrix();
        r2 +=1;
    }
}
```

The void `rosace();` is the one that I'd like to be non-animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're storing `r1` as a global variable. This means that it keeps it's value after every iteration.

Instead, make it a local variable:

```
void rosace() {
    int r1 = 0;

    for (i1 = 0; i1<230; i1++) {
        rectMode(CENTER);

        noFill();
        stroke(20);
        strokeWeight(1);

        pushMatrix();
        translate(width/2, height/2);
        translate(400, 400);
        rotate(radians(r1));
        rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        r1 +=1;

        popMatrix();
        println("rosace ex");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's doing what I want now !

Answer (score 0):

You can't just keep a part of the scene, when animations are drawn on top of it. You have to draw the entire scene in every frame. Ensure that `rosace` draws the same in every frame.

Just set `r1 = 0` in every frame, then the algorithm in `rosace` generates the same rectangles in every frame:

```java
void rosace(){
    r1 = 0;

    for (i1 = 0;i1<230; i1++){
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it !